# Rebase detached HEAD to master

Tags: git

Hi can you help me solve that problem? I am on a branch **(HEAD detached from refs/heads/master) where I have some new commits and I need add these changes into my master branch. an you tell me how to do that? Here is my output from terminal after entering `git branch` and `git status`
**

```
denis@N56VJ:~/Workspace/ita-javaee-04$ git status
HEAD detached from refs/heads/master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        src/main/webapp/package-lock.json

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
denis@N56VJ:~/Workspace/ita-javaee-04$ git branch
* (HEAD detached from refs/heads/master)
  master
denis@N56VJ:~/Workspace/ita-javaee-04$
```

Comment: Just create a branch with `git checkout -b <new-branch-name>`, and continue from there...

Comment: is possible continue in master branch or should I create new branch xxx and next rebase xxx to master?

Comment: You can continue with master. Use `git checkout -B master` in this case.

Comment: @Opal thank you :)

Comment: Let me know if that worked.

Comment: @Opal `git checkout -B master` is dangerous, and should not be recommended to a git-newbie: It may loose commits at `master`!

Comment: @cmaster, you are absolutely right, I inferred that `master` is out of OP interest. Could have been wrong.

Comment: @DenisStephanov, and? You fixed it?

Comment: @Opal Yes, it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delete your old master and create a new one at your current HEAD.

```
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master
```

If you're worried aboud making a mistake, then be sure to `git show HEAD`, `git show master`, and save the sha1 hashes as a backup.  Alternatively, you can rely on `git reflog`.